# Zeit now.json => an error occurs after deployment

Tags: node.js, vercel

When I follow the link where app is deployed, it says `Cannot GET /`. Whet I follow routes `/users` or `/user/10`, it says `404: NOT_FOUND Code: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`. Help please, what can be possibly wrong? 
This is structure of my files in project:

```
server
├── data
│   ├── users.json
│   └── users_statistic.json
├── index.js  
├── package.json   
├── now.json       
├── package-lock.json
├── .gitignore
├── .nowignore
└── node_modules
    └── stuff...
```

And this is `now.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "node-lambda",
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { 
            "src":  "index.js", 
            "use": "@now/node-server",
            "config": {
                "includeFiles": [
                    "data/**"
                ]
            } 
        }       
    ],
    "routes": [     
        { "src": "/users", "methods": ["POST"],  "dest": "/index.js" },
        { "src": "/user/(?<id>[^/]*)", "methods": ["POST"],  "dest": "/index.js" }      
    ]
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Production
const origin = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'prod-url';
app.use(cors({ origin }));


//Getting data from files
const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/users.json', 'utf8'));
const users_statistic = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/users_statistic.json', 'utf8'));
...
```

Comment: can you update your questions with your `index.js`

Comment: I did, but it's very large...

Answer (score 0):

in json

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [{
    "src": "index.js",
    "use": "@now/node-server"
}],
"routes": [{
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    },
    "src": "/.*",
    "dest": "/index.js"
}]
```

}